Converting between diagonalizations of a linear transformation with respect to different basis
I was originally asked to find a transition matrix $T$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $D=T^{-1}[\theta]_{e,e}T$ for matrix representation of a linear transformation $\theta:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb R^3$, "$\textbf e$".
Because of easier computations, I instead diagonalized the matrix representation of the linear transformation with respect to some non-standard basis $u$ of $\mathbb R^3$, i.e., I have $[\theta]_{u,u}=PDP^{-1}$, can I somehow get the diagonalisation for the standard basis?
That is, I want to know the diagonalisation of $[\theta]_{e,e}$, i.e., find $D'=T^{-1}[\theta]_{e,e}T$.
I have a strong feeling that I can use some change of basis or transition matrix, but whatever I try, the result is not ending up as a diagonal matrix.

You have $D=P^{-1}[\theta]_u P$, but $[\theta]_u=Q^{-1}[\theta]_e Q$ for $Q$ a change of basis matrix. What happens when you substitute?
